# dplyr split-apply-combine with list column

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a `tibble` with two columns: a group variable (grp) and a list-column
containing matrices of equal dimension (mat).

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(2, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2)
mat2 <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2)
mat3 <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 2), nrow = 2)
mat4 <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2)

df <- tibble(grp = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
             mat = list(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4))
```

**Edit:**

I want to calculate the mean matrix by group, and add it as a new list-column. I.e. The new column should be:

```
list(matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2),
     matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2),
     matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2),
     matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2))
```

The best I can do is:

```
df_out <- df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(n = n(),
         mean_mat = list(Reduce('+', mat) / n)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

It works, but I'm trying to understand why the call to `list` is necessary, and also hoping to find an alternative approach (either tidyverse or base R) that is perhaps simpler.

Comment: `mean(list(mat1, mat2))` throws an error for me - what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Same, I get `NA` as a result, with a warning: "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Comment: Huh, I see it only worked b/c I had a bunch of packages loaded (but can't figure out which package specifically). Anyway, I want `df$mean_mat` to be a list with 4 matrices: `matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 2)` (x2), then `matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2)` (x2)

Comment: It works because you save the NAs in a list. If you run df_out$mean_mat you see that it is still all NA

Comment: You need the call to the list because you want to save a matrix in a data.frame.